# Old 90s TV show - Guy fights aliens in a suit

Tags: story-identification

There was a TV show when I was growing up that I'd love to watch again (even though I'm sure it won't be the same).
Here is what I remember:

1. He was a young adult
2. He had an alien car (red I think) and an alien bike (yellow?) that transformed, sorta. Both vehicles talked.
3. Can't remember the car's name but the bike was chuppa or something, and he said "chuppa form up" or similar to call the bike to his position.
4. He said some phrase to transform, and wore a belt which, in the transformation animation became part of his suit. I think it was near his head so I can only guess his eyes.
5. He had a full suit that was green ish, but sometimes he had an extra powerful suit that looked slightly different.
6. I'm pretty sure he was an alien but looked human and was adopted by some family.

That's most of what I remember, hopefully some comment/answer can trigger more information.

Edit: Show details

7. It was a TV series, I can't remember how many seasons/episodes.
8. It was live action.
9. It was around 1998-2002 when I saw it, but I lived in New Zealand and back then it took many years for us to get TV show so it was probably broadcast a few years earlier.
10. He fought aliens to save his town/maybe earth, it was the old school fighting where they barely made contact for a "punch".
11. I think it was mostly martial art style fights, but he may have had some specials weapons.
12. It was in English.
13. As [Quentin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6806/quentin) pointed out, it may be an English/American remake of the Kamen rider series.

Comment: It's animation, right? Take a look at this [meta post](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for list of details you can add.

Comment: No it's live action. I'll have a look at that post and edit as best I can. Thanks for the link!

Comment: Sounds like it might be a dubbed version of one of the [Kamen Rider Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamen_Rider_Series). I don't know the series well enough to narrow it down any further. Do the character pictures from any of the shows in the series look familiar?

Comment: YES! that guy looks quite similar to what I remember the main protagonist looking like.

Comment: @Quentin quick! Post it and get rep!

Comment: I suspect / fear it was Saban's version of Kamen Rider Black RX, simply titled "Masked Rider". Many facets of the original story were changed, and they added a "cute" alien sidekick that looked vaguely like Howard the Duck. It is widely considered to be WILDLY inferior to the original, as opposed to their "Power Rangers" adaptations of the Super Sentai series, which vary from only "somewhat" inferior to "quite" inferior. To summarize, if you liked it, seek out the original - you will likely enjoy it more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Quentin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/6806/quentin) suggested and [VBartilucci](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/64282/vbartilucci) confirmed, the series I was looking for was Masked Rider.
Here are some additional details about it incase anyone else searches for it at some point:

1. It was an American adaptation of the Japanese Kamen Rider Black RX series.
2. It aired from September 1995 to November 1996
3. The main character is Dex, who has a pet alien called Ferbus, who looks similar to a furby.
4. Dex was from the planet Edenoi, and the main antagonists of the series are called Edenoites, led by Dex's uncle, Count Dregon.
5. There was also a cross over with Mighty Morphin Power Rangers.
6. Dex's adopted family were the Stewarts. The dad and daughter were white, the mum Asian, and the son black.
7. He had a red car named Magno and a yellow biked named Chopper, both of whom could talk.